# How to Enable Password Plugin on Roundcube

Tags: email, settings, roundcube

I recently installed Roundcube on to manage my emails. However, Rouncube does not come with a feature to enable email users to change their passwords.
I was able to enable the Roundcube Password plugin.

[image: See image here]

On trying to change the Password I got an error that *New password could not be saved.*

[image: Error Image]

Please I need help configuring the Password Plugin config.inc.php file.

Answer (score 2):

can you check if you have updated the configuration files on password plugin.

- login to server
- open password plugin folder
- copy config.inc.php.dist to config.inc.php
- edit the lines: (i am supposing you have mysql db)

  ```
   $config['password_driver'] = 'sql';

   $config['password_dovecotpw'] = '/usr/local/sbin/doveadm pw'; // for dovecot-2.x

   $config['password_dovecotpw_method'] = 'CRAM-MD5';

   $config['password_username_format'] = '%u';

   $config['password_db_dsn'] = 'mysql://databaseuser:databasepassword@localhost/databasename';

   $config['password_query'] = 'UPDATE mailbox SET password=%c WHERE username=%u';

   $config['password_crypt_hash'] = 'md5';

   $config['password_hash_algorithm'] = 'sha1';
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The configurations above worked fine, but you also have to give access for the roundcube user access to update,select on the maildb.users database

```
#mysql -u root -p
mysql>GRANT SELECT,UPDATE on maildb.users to 'roundcube'@'localhost';
mysql>flush privileges;
mysql>quit
```

Thanks